# linking error on parsing java.time.LocalDate in scalajs

Tags: scala, scala.js, localdate

When I want to parse LocalDate in scalajs, linking error occur:

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse("2016-11-11")
```

here is the error message:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent method java.time.LocalDate$.parse(java.lang.CharSequence)java.time.LocalDate
[error]   called from example.ScalaJSExample$$anonfun$myview$1.applyOrElse(scala.collection.immutable.List,scala.Function1)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from example.ScalaJSExample$$anonfun$myview$1.applyOrElse(java.lang.Object,scala.Function1)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from scala.concurrent.Future$class.$$anonfun$1(scala.concurrent.Future,scala.PartialFunction,scala.util.Try)java.lang.Object
```

but using java.time.LocalDate.of(2016,11,11) works without any error.

What is the problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `java.time.LocalDate.parse` is not implemented. You might try another of the alternative libraries for `java.time` support, if one of them supports it. Otherwise, I guess you could contribute the implementation.